# Prioritizing Security Updates Across Web Server

Tags: linux, security, web-server, update

Single web server with LAMP stack, OpenSSL, and one Drupal site running on it. There are security updates available for the Linux Kernel, Apache, MySQL, PHP, OpenSSL, and Drupal.

Generally, is there a best practice for prioritizing these updates by risk of exploitation? Are there technical reasons one should be the higher priority for applying security updates vs another?

My initial thought was the the public facing pieces such as Drupal, OpenSSL and Apache are the highest priority for getting security updates applied since they are the most vulnerable to the outside world/the first to fall.

I was thinking of 'priority' defined as how quickly an update is applied after it is released (hours, day, months) or by frequency (every x weeks or months) updates are applied.

In that case, my ranking from highest to lowest priority:

- Drupal
- OpenSSL
- Apache
- PHP
- MySQL
- Linux Kernel

I realize this this would depend on the severity of each vulnerability and other factors but looking for best practice with reasoning if possible.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I tried to do my due diligence and search for an existing question on this topic so thank you! Apparently I didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Some things can be hard to find. I know about that post mainly because I wrote it. :)